# How can I display a text message based on the day of the week using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display a message/text based on the day of the week using JavaScript into a HTML file. I'm not an expert when it comes to JavaScript and I have been beating myself up with this. This what I have thus far

```
    var specials;
    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

    if (days == Monday) {
      specials = "$4.00 Burgers All Day";
    } 
    
    if (days == Tuesday) {
      specials = "$1.25 Tacos All Day";
    }

    if (days == Wednesday) {
        specials = "$0.70 Wings All Day";
    }

    if (days == Thursday) {
        specials = "$6.49 Steak or Chicken Philly";
    }

    if (days == Friday) {
        specials = "";
    }
    if (days == Saturday) {
        specials = "";
    }
    if (days == Sunday) {
        specials = "";
    }
    document.getElementById("specials").innerHTML = specials;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `var d = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();`

Comment: `days` is an array. How do you expect `if (days == Monday)` to ever be true?

Comment: I suggest using an object like `const dailySpecials = {Monday: "$4.00 Burgers All Day", Tuesday: "$1.25 Tacos All Day", ...};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```js
let specials;
const currentDay = new Date().getDay();

// from sunday to saturday
switch(currentDay) {
  case 0:
    specials = '';
    break;
 case 1:
    specials = '$4.00 Burgers All Day';
    break;
 case 2:
    specials = '$1.25 Tacos All Day';
    break;
 case 3:
    specials = '$0.70 Wings All Day';
    break;
 case 4:
   specials = '$6.49 Steak or Chicken Philly';
    break;
 case 5:
    specials = '';
    break;
 case 6:
    specials = '';
    break;
}

document.getElementById("specials").innerHTML = specials;
```

```html
<h2 id="specials"></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Date` object you can get the current Date/time and then get the day from it like so.

```
const currentDay = new Date(Date.now()).getDay();
```

It maps to 0 through 6,  Sunday through Saturday. Which would just be the indices in your array.

`days[0]; //Sunday`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Answer (score 0):

```
var specials;
    var day = "Monday" /* <-- for Example */

    // "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"

    if (day == "Monday") {
      specials = "$4.00 Burgers All Day";
    } 
    
    if (day == "Tuesday") {
      specials = "$1.25 Tacos All Day";
    }

    if (day == "Wednesday") {
        specials = "$0.70 Wings All Day";
    }

    if (day == "Thursday") {
        specials = "$6.49 Steak or Chicken Philly";
    }

    if (day == "Friday") {
        specials = "";
    }
    if (day == "Saturday") {
        specials = "";
    }
    if (day == "Sunday") {
        specials = "";
    }
    document.getElementById("specials").innerHTML = specials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using getDay and an array

```js
var specials = [
"foo",
"bar",
"baz",
"goober",
"funky",
"chicken",
"dinner"
];

var d = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = d.getDay();
document.getElementById("out").textContent = specials[dayOfWeek];
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using momentjs.  You need to create today's date, and get day out of today's variable, use switch statement to get your values, also since friday thru sun values are same, just use default case.

```
    var specials;
    var today=moment();
    var day= today.day();
    console.log("day",day)
    switch(day){
    case 1:
     specials = "$0.70 Wings All Day";
    break;
    case 2:
     specials = "$1.25 Tacos All Day";
    break;
      case 3:
       specials = "$0.70 Wings All Day";
    break;
      case 4:
        specials = "$6.49 Steak or Chicken Philly";
    break;
     default:
         specials = "";
    break;
    }
console.log(specials)
```

Answer (score 0):

But guys, use an object! This is the simplest, and probably the fastest,  there is no logic.

```js
const days = {
  "Sunday" : "",
  "Monday" : "$4.00 Burgers All Day",
  "Tuesday" : "$1.25 Tacos All Day" ,
  "Wednesday" : "$0.70 Wings All Day",
  "Thursday" : "$6.49 Steak or Chicken Philly'",
  "Friday" : "",
  "Saturday" : ""
}

/* Example monday */
console.log(
  days["Monday"]
)
```